# Docker compose Error response from daemon, Ports are not available on Windows 11

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-compose

I have following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  ## NGINX
  nginx:
    container_name: zl-nginx
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - reza
    ports:
      - 172.100.0.1:80:80

networks:
  reza:
    name: reza
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.100.0.0/24
    attachable: true
```

When I run `docker compose up` (as administrator) I will get the following error:
`Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 172.100.0.1:80 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 172.100.0.1:80: can't bind on the specified endpoint`
I am using Windows 11 and IIS is not installed and the port is not assigned to any other service and it is free.

I have tested same docker file on Linux and it will work there.

could you please guide me what is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: I upgraded to Docker Desktop 4.22 and am getting the same error on my Windows 11 machine even though `netstat -a` shows nothing using the required port.